# Non-Capturing group regex not working in Java

Tags: java, regex

The online REGEX testers shows the non-captuting groups are getting ignored but from java code it is not ignored.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?:execute: ID: \\[\\s)([0-9]*)(?:\\s\\])");
        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher("controllers.pring execute: ID: [ 290825814 ] executing bean: [ strong ]");
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
execute: ID: [ 290825814 ]
```

Expected

```
290825814
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is wrong assumption as `matcher.group(0)` always returns you full matched text by your latest `find` or `matches` methods.

To get `290825814` you must use:

```
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?:execute: ID: \\[\\s)([0-9]*)(?:\\s\\])");
Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher("controllers.pring execute: ID: [ 290825814 ] executing bean: [ strong ]");
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // 290825814
}
```

Comment: Darn ! How could not I see that :) Thanks @anubhava

Comment: Thanks, It was quick. Usually SOF is active in the night :)

Comment: What is the point of using a non-capturing group if is captured anyway? In your example, making groups 0 and 2 capturing would produce the same result?

Comment: Unnecessary groups should be avoided to conserve memory while executing regex and preserving additional group numbers.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Matcher documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)):

> Capturing groups are indexed from left to right, starting at one. Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression m.group(0) is equivalent to m.group().

Because you are using group 0, you are capturing the entire pattern, coincidentally the same as your non-capturing group. I'm not sure why you have the entire pattern wrapped in a non-capturing group.